# Wait in Node.js app until neo4j is ready: Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, neo4j

I'm having a Kubernetes deployment containing my Node.js app and a neo4j service. The problem is that, neo4j takes some seconds to start (15M nodes - but same effect even when the graph is empty), but my app is already trying to run a query:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

async function start() {
    var driver = neo4j.driver(
        'neo4j://localhost',
        neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password')
      )
      
    var session = driver.session()

    // Create admin upon start...
    await session.run('MERGE (n:user {name: "Admin"})')
}

start()
```

The query fails with "Neo4jError: Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available." because neo4j is still starting. When I restart my app some seconds after neo4j has been started completely, everything works as expected. So the question is: How can I wait in my Node.js application (or instruct Kubernetes) to wait until neo4j is ready?

The yaml for my deployment is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: neo4j
          image: neo4j:4.2.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7474
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: neo4j

        - name: node-app
          image: some-image-from-container-registry

      volumes:
        - name: neo4j
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: neo4j-pv
```

Comment: I don't know this module, but you can try to add an await in front of `neo4j.driver(...)` and hope that it's asynchronous.